# Using Vite js how to stop scss compilation to css which are inside vue js sfc files (particularly in vite library mode)?

Tags: vue.js, sass, vite, rollup, bundling-and-minification

I am building a design system library with using vue3 and vite as builder (in library mode).
Lets take this example vue sfc file below :

```
// Header.vue
 
<template>
  <div class="header"> </div>
</template>
<script lang="ts" setup>

</script>
<style scoped lang="scss">

.header {
  color: $header__primary !default
}
</style>
```

Here I would like the styles to be extracted in a separate file(just like the way it is by default in vite library mode) but skip the compilation to css, Output will be like this:

```
// style.scss
.header { color: $header__primary !default }
```

I would like to do this so that the customers of my library can override the values according to their brand needs from their end.

By default in production build, vite compiles all of my scss styles inside **.vue** files to css and concats to one **style.css** file , i would just like to stop the compilation part only and provide it as **style.scss** file.

I have tried looking into documentation of both vite and rollup but unsuccessful so far, under the hood vite uses rollup in production build so suggestions with rollup is also welcome.

Comment: This requirement is exotic. Just don't keep the styles in <style> if you really need them in separate files

Comment: @EstusFlask not sure how it is exotic but after the build vite automatically extracts all css inside <style> </style> of .vue files and dumps them all in a single style.css file, i am just asking for a way for the style.css to be in style.scss and not compile the sass variables in the built output, which i will provide to the consumers of my library.

Comment: .vue to .css is compilation process. .vue to .scss is something else. I'd expect there's no ready to use solution because nobody does that. It's likely possible but you'd need to write custom Rollup plugin for that. The proper way to do what you want is to keep SASS styles in separate files